# Timer Tick not increasing values on time interval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to increase values on timer tick event but it is not increasing don't know what I am forgetting it is showing only `1`.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>

private int i = 0;

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;

    Label3.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For that use-case, you really need to use JavaScript (I guess your actual code is more complex though and _needs_ something server-side)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ViewState to store and then read the value of `i` again.

```
int i = 0;

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the viewstate with the value exists
    if (ViewState["timerValue"] != null)
    {
        //cast the viewstate back to an int
        i = (int)ViewState["timerValue"];
    }

    i++;

    Label3.Text = i.ToString();

    //store the value in the viewstate
    ViewState["timerValue"] = i;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. And if you want to save the value of `i` across multiple pages or still having the value after pressing F5 or reloading the page, use `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the form is posted back and then assign values. Check [IsPostBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
private int i;

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i = Int32.Parse(Label3.Text);
        i++;           
    }

    Label3.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it is not a good practice to store values inside of views (such as asp.net page). It could be overwritten each time the request is sent.

You could store your data elsewhere:

```
public static class StaticDataStorage
{
    public static int Counter = 0;
}
```

And use it:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StaticDataStorage.Counter++;
    Label3.Text = StaticDataStorage.Counter.ToString();
}
```